# GPSD Port 2947 taken by 1/init

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, systemd, gpsd

I am currently running TWO raspberry pi's, lets call them WORKING PI and non working pi.

**WORKING PI**:

- Model B Rev 2
- Jessie 4.1.19+ #858
- gpsd revision 3.11-3+deb8ul
- This unit was upgraded from the original Wheezy distro to this version of
  Jessie. Use to have a working TL-WN725N wireless connection under
  Wheezy, but this was rendered inoperable after the Jessie upgrade.

**non working pi**

- Model B Rev 2+
- Jessie 4.1.7+ #817
- gpsd revision 3.11-3
- This is the original distro, but have updated to the latest version.
- This unit has a working TL-WN725N wireless connection.

What both pi's have in common:

- RPI GPS Add On hat both running U-Blox 6 gps chipsets.
- when commanded with *gpsmon /dev/ttyAMA0*, both pi's regurgitate the expected gps NMEA strings
- Can load the gpsmon command with the u-blox driver and switch between NMEA and U-Blox formatted gps data.

**The Problem**
The ultimate goal is to have gps data logged by both pi's using python. To do that, it appears (as far as I can glean) there must be a gpsd socket running. This can be verified using **cgps -s**. This is functional in the WORKING PI, but fails in the non working pi.

I have started the gpsd service with the following command in both pi's

*sudo gpsd /dev/ttyAMA0 -b -N -D 3 -n -F /var/run/gpsd.sock*

In the WORKING PI, this command is accepted and cgps -s runs correctly. Furthermore, the following information is provided:

```
$ sudo netstat -ltnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      498/ser2net
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      498/ser2net
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      498/ser2net
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      452/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      369/inetd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      498/ser2net
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      769/exim4
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      498/ser2net
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      814/0
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6011          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20461/2
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6012          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6177/5
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6013          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6236/7
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2947          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8609/gpsd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      452/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      769/exim4
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      814/0
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6011                :::*                    LISTEN      20461/2
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6012                :::*                    LISTEN      6177/5
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6013                :::*                    LISTEN      6236/7
tcp6       0      0 ::1:2947                :::*                    LISTEN      8609/gpsd
```

This is what I expect: both IPv4 and IPv6 2947 sockets are being used by the gpsd service.

Now, with the non working pi:

```
$ sudo gpsd /dev/ttyAMA0 -b -N D 3 -n -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv4 port gpsd, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv6 port gpsd, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
```

In response to the netstat command:

```
$ sudo netstat -ltnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2947          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      564/ser2net
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      564/ser2net
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      564/ser2net
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      477/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      564/ser2net
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      564/ser2net
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      882/0
tcp6       0      0 ::1:2947                :::*                    LISTEN      1/init
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      477/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN      882/0
```

Clearly, both IPv4 and IPv6 2947 sockets are being used by the init service (I'm a RF hardware guy, not a software guy, but this sounds like the operating system is controlling the port.

I have compared the following files between the two pi's and found them to be identical:

```
/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.socket
/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.service
/etc/default/gpsd
```

I have spent the last 2 weeks combing this site and others and tried the solutions presented there (to no avail). It appears that this in not an uncommon problem. I welcome any help, but my 3 main questions are:

1. Why does init not capture port 2947 at boot in the WORKING PI, whereas the non working pi does capture it, even though both pi's are running Jessie 4.1 (though I admit different rev's). Clearly the reason the non working pi cannot mount a gpsd socket is because the port it wants is already taken.
2. Is there a way to tell the non working pi NOT to capture port 2947, or is there a way for me to make init relinquish that port from the command line?
3. Is it possible, the wireless on the non working pi is using these ports and that's why gpsd can grab the port on the WORKING PI (which does not have wireless) and can't on the non working pi  (which has a working wireless).

I'm out of ideas.

---

I'm not quite sure if I'm supposed to ADD COMMENT, EDIT THE POST or ANSWER THE QUESTION. In response to LARSKS first answer:

I'll chronicle each pi separately.

**non working pi**

Upon rebooting the pi:

```
$ systemctl is-enabled gpsd.socket
enabled
$ systemctl is-enabled gpsd.service
static
```

cgps -s or cgps still does not work (it times out)

Though, it appears the socket and service are present. So, I tried telneting in to port 2947:

```
$ sudo telnet localhost 2947
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
{"class":"VERSION","release":"3.11","rev":"3.11-3","proto_major":3,"proto_minor":9}
?WATCH={"enable":true, "json"}
{"class":"DEVICES","devices":[]}
{"class":"WATCH","enable":true,"json":false,"nmea":false,"raw":0,"scaled":false,"timing":false,"split24":false,"pps":false}
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

The connection just hangs.

gpsmon /dev/ttyAMA0 still functions properly.

**WORKING PI**

```
$ systemctl is-enabled gpsd.socket
disabled
$ systemctl is-enabled gpsd.service
static
```

This is what I expected, so I attempted to start the service as I did before:

```
$ sudo gpsd /dev/ttyAMA0 -b -N D 3 -n -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
gpsd:ERROR: device open failed: No such file or directory - retrying read-only
gpsd:ERROR: read-only device open failed: No such file or directory
gpsd:ERROR: initial GPS device D open failed
gpsd:ERROR: device open failed: No such file or directory - retrying read-only
gpsd:ERROR: read-only device open failed: No such file or directory
gpsd:ERROR: initial GPS device 3 open failed
gpsd:ERROR: device open failed: No such file or directory - retrying read-only
gpsd:ERROR: read-only device open failed: No such file or directory
gpsd:ERROR: D: device activation failed.
gpsd:ERROR: device open failed: No such file or directory - retrying read-only
gpsd:ERROR: read-only device open failed: No such file or directory
gpsd:ERROR: 3: device activation failed.
gpsd:ERROR: device open failed: No such file or directory - retrying read-only
gpsd:ERROR: read-only device open failed: No such file or directory
gpsd:ERROR: D: device activation failed.
gpsd:ERROR: device open failed: No such file or directory - retrying read-only
gpsd:ERROR: read-only device open failed: No such file or directory
gpsd:ERROR: 3: device activation failed.
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo gpsd /dev/ttyAMA0 -b -N D 3 -n -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
```

This is now different. In fact, when I attempt to run cgps, I just get a blank screen. Previously I would get an empty table, but now, nothing.

When I attempt to run gpsmon /dev/ttyAMA0, I get:

```
$ gpsmon /dev/ttyAMA0
gpsmon:ERROR: device open failed: Device or resource busy - retrying read-only
gpsmon:ERROR: read-only device open failed: Device or resource busy
gpsmon: activation of device /dev/ttyAMA0 failed, errno=16 (Device or resource busy)
```

But, if I reboot, gpsmon /dev/ttyAMA0 returns to normal operation.

As a footnote:

```
$ systemctl enable --now gpsd.socket
systemctl: unrecognized option '--now'
```

As a general observation, the gpsmon /dev/ttyAMA0 command works because I am just streaming NMEA msgs via the serial port, to my screen.

the cgps (or python code) does not work, because the socket and or service is not working.

Comment: In the first example it looks as if you were able to successfully telnet to the gpsd port and receive a response from the daemon. That suggests that if something isn't work as expected it's a gpsd configuration problem, because otherwise the service appears to be up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a different port with gpsd? Use the -S flag to specify the port.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer to me. One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32930797)

Comment: Looks like the default port is 2947 (as stated on the Linux man page). After reading this I switched to a really high number (9000) and it work as expected. Thanks for the suggestion.